# Is there a way to lock a file in Komodo Edit?

Tags: api, locking, file-permissions, komodoedit

Our team uses ActiveState Komodo Edit to edit files on remote hosts. Is there a way (like in VIM) to lock a file for editing if it is already opened for editing?

Answer (score 2):

Use a macro to toggle readonly mode for the current tab:

```
// Toggle colouring of and readonly on current tab
var view = ko.views.manager.currentView;
var scimoz = view.scimoz;
var tab = view.parentNode._tab;
if (tab.style.backgroundColor) {
    tab.style.cssText = "outline-color: -moz-use-text-color; outline-style: none; outline-width: medium;";
    if (scimoz.readOnly) scimoz.readOnly = false;
}  else {
    tab.style.cssText = "background: #FF8080;";
    scimoz.readOnly = true;
}
```

**References**

- [Komodo IDE/Edit Release Notes](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/9.0/releases/ide.html)
- [Macro no longer works in Komodo 9 - Customization - Komodo IDE & Edit | Forums](http://community.komodoide.com/t/macro-no-longer-works-in-komodo-9/1427)
- [Scintilla Documentation: SCI_SETREADONLY](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETREADONLY)